# What variables are available for apache vhost template?

Tags: apache, templates, vhosts, cwp

I'm using the cwp server to manage my centos 7 machine. In template files for apache vhosts I find such variables as

> %domain_idn%

> %user%

but nowhere can I find a list of available variables (I'm actually looking for the parent domain of a subdomain as a variable). So I have two questions:

- Are these variables set up by apache or is this something that cwp have added?
- Where can I find a list of the variables available?

Many thanks